# When pass value of field name without unit of measure it give error so How to solve?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I work on SQL Server 2012 query - I get an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Code:

```
SELECT  
    LEFT([Impedance], PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', [Impedance]) - 1) AS [Impedance],
    RIGHT([Impedance], LEN([Impedance]) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', [Impedance]) + 1) AS [ImpedanceUnits] 
FROM
    ##NewTable0
```

I have a column `Impedance` with values such as `50kg` as example. It splits this values to `50` and `kg` without any issue.

Problem occurs when the column contains only `50`, without any unit of measure.

In this case, I get an error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUB STRING function.

How to solve this error please?

To summarize my issue : how to handle error when column `impedance` has a number only, such as `50` - to work without causing an error?

- `50kg` is working fine
- `50` causes an error

**Update**: I don't have any issue on number with unit of measure as `50kg`, I only have an issue when I have only a number, such as `50`, without unit of measure.

This is my issue below I need to solve

```
SELECT 
    Impedacte = (CASE 
                    WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', '50') > 0 
                       THEN LEFT('50', PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', '50') - 1) 
                       ELSE '50' 
                 END),
    ImpedanceUnits = (CASE 
                         WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', '50') > 0 
                            THEN RIGHT('50', (LEN('50') - PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', '50') + 1))
                            ELSE NULL 
                      END)
```

Comment: Please check this out. https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/14/sql-server-get-numeric-value-from-alpha-numeric-string-udf-for-get-numeric-numbers-only/

Comment: sorry I don't need that I have issue when I pass number only as 50 but when number with unit of measure as 50kg not have any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an extra character so the `PATINDEX()` returns an appropriate value:

```
LEFT([Impedance], PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%', [Impedance] + ' ') - 1) AS [Impedance],
```